# django 1.8 what does <a href="{% url "post_detail" pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a> do

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

im learning django from [djangogirls](http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/extend_your_application/index.html)

i cannot understand what below code block does while extending an application called "blog". i googled but could not find related examples.
i have this template file named **post_list.html** which extends a **base.html** and looks like

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="post">
            <div class="date">
                {{ post.published_date }}
            </div>
        <h1><a href="{% url "post_detail" pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>   #confused part here ??

        <p>{{ post.text|linebreaks }}</p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}


i dont have post.pk in any model and dont know how it is assigned to "pk"   variable

<h1><a href="{% url "post_detail" pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a> 

</h1>
```

Below is what app url and model look like

```
#models.py
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

def publish(self):
    self.published_date = timezone.now()
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title



#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post
def post_list(request):
    posts =     Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})    

def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})

#urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, all django models get a primary key called `id`; even if you do not specify one in `models.py`.

`.pk` is an [automatic generated property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#the-pk-lookup-shortcut) for each model that is assigned by django and it refers to the primary key.

The reason `.pk` is used is because it will always return the primary key value, no matter what the *actual* primary key field is. So if you decide to have a model where you have your own primary key (and thus, django is not creating one for you) `.pk` will still work.

Comment: thanks Burhan Khalid, that cleared up the clouds for me. Is the django generated primary key is stored permanently to associated model objects?

Comment: Yes; otherwise the ForeignKey relations would not work.